# Answers flagged as spam, moderator rejects

Tags: discussion, spam

I periodically browse Stack Overflow and clean after a lot of users. Today I stumbled upon a user that I think spammed with his purchasable scripts. [HERE +17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26242557), [HERE +7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26662475) and [HERE +6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26667189). Same answers with a different approach.

IMHO, the user has intentionally registered to promote his tools and posted the same answers to three different questions. None of them are fixing users' problems; it is just marketing. I would consider it SPAM since here we are not selling code.

I have flagged them as SPAM, but the conclusion is: `a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`.

Are they SPAM or I am wrong?

Comment: If you notice a user posting several such answer which (I think) are not blatantly obvious spam, use an "other" flag and have a mod look at it. Explain in detail what you're seeing and your chances of a helpful flag will be higher.

Comment: Bart is right. The fact is that linking to a tool that you have to pay for is not *in and of itself sufficient* to make a post spam. The first post (with a score of +17), for instance, contains code showing how to use the tool. I can see how a moderator would decline a spam flag raised on it. This being said, a user whose entire 3 contributions to SO are suggesting to use the same tool (free or not) seems suspicious to me, but this suspicion can only be conveyed in a custom flag.

Comment: Yeah, something else is at play here. The original answer with +17 wasn't all that great at first. The flags were not declined by me. If not the user, then whoever voted on their posts.

Comment: @Bart `spam` answers ARE looked at by moderators, all spam flags pop up on the moderator dashboard (apparently) which is why they're dealt with quickly.

Comment: That's besides my point @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ. If it's not blatantly obvious (and these weren't at first glance) they might well be dismissed as invalid flags. The "other" flag allows you to explain a bit more in that case and that might help to clarify the situation significantly where a mod might not see what you figured out. (p.s. by all means help us out by flagging network-wide spam in the Tavern. Loads of fun ;) )

Comment: @Bart: That sounds to me like the spam flag is not doing it's (intended) job properly and thus should be dropped at all.

Comment: Sure @JensG, the rare occasions that a spam flag might not have the intended effect are absolutely a justification to drop them entirely.

Comment: @Bart sarcasm works less well with diverse audience and in text. But I got it. *Admits to reading it twice*

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You're absolutely right.

The thing behind these is that the user created 10+ additional accounts to vote for his spam answers so they looked like legitimate answers. I imagine the original flags probably got declined because they were so highly upvoted and have been on the site for quite a while already. Generally, spam flags alone don't prompt us to look into voting patterns, but that odd feeling made me look.

In addition, they also tried to edit their spam into other posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5990425) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5943149)

Before being deleted, their three answers dropped to 7, 1, and 0. This user was clearly not here for the right purposes and only wanted to advertise a product. Spam destroyed.

Just for the sake of mentioning it, his sock-puppet accounts were also involved in posting the same blatant spam:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961913/image-resize-before-upload/28121858#28121858)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607707/what-is-the-best-way-to-resize-crop-an-image-on-client-side/26855840#26855840)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591380/javascript-image-crop-rectangle-select-on-image/26670233#26670233)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769274/cropping-a-upload-preview-with-jquery/26772510#26772510)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735786/upload-and-crop-image-before-sending-it-to-the-server/26615955#26615955)
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626190/resizing-image-before-upload/27269300#27269300)
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206063/component-to-upload-multiple-images-with-client-side-crop/26968451#26968451)

Comment: Good, thank you. Good to know my investigation skills are up-to-date :)

Comment: The most odd thing is that "last seen" on his profile: `seen 16 hours ago`

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why a one-year suspension instead of outright account destruction? Surely you don't think a spammer with that number of socks will change into a worthy community member in the space of one year?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Because he appears to be an actual legitimate person and I wanted to send him a message. I did have a short debate with myself which method I was going to use.

Comment: A few of the questions you linked to should be closed now as off-topic asking for a tool or software recommendation.

Comment: I'm vaguely curious about the two accounts who commented on the first (the HERE+17) answer.  They're from the same place, same age, same interests, and both had two major reputation drops - one in october one in may, in both cases on the same day - when a user (or users) was removed - and the latter (October 27) also was coincidental with the main user here.  Did you look to see if they're possibly sockpuppets of each other?

Comment: Wait, I can create a sock-puppet account and upvote myself? This is _awesome!_

Comment: @matt - Yeah, it is the best thing evarr! See you next year ;)