# False positive flags got me flagging disabled only in Triage Reviews

Tags: discussion, support, bug, declined-flags

Yesterday I found [a user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284768/answers-flagged-as-spam-moderator-rejects) which was debated here and found guilty of spam :)

Problem is that initially my flags were declined and then approved. Now when I try to flag something I get this error:

[image: Too many of your recent flags have been declined]

Is this normal? My last declined flag (except the ones yesterday) is over three and a half years ago.

Later edit:

This seems to be only in Triage Reviews, I can flag normally in other places. Initial flags were not in Triage. It seems to me like a bug.

If I enable (forced) those radio boxes ... everything works as expected.

Comment: That you were blocked from further flagging is not a bug, that is normal. But given the circumstances, there could be grounds for a a moderator to lift the (temporary) ban early.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't think moderators can lift the flag ban -- they can't give flag bans in the first place.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: hrm, they can lift just about all other bans, I don't see why flagging would be any different there. But if they can't, they can't, and the OP will just have to sit it out.

Comment: How many declined flags do you have? At the worst, IIRC, it's flags from the past 10 days that are accounted in flag bans, so if a mod doesn't save you, you won't be able to use flags for a week.

Comment: Only 3 flags :). Maybe someone will save me at some point ... or I will relax for a week :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yeah, the flag ban stuff (like question bans) is all system-side, so we can't override it. Review bans and suspensions are things we can change, because we can manually issue those to begin with. Without any outstanding flags of Mihai's for us to approve, I don't know that there's anything we can do here, unfortunately.

Comment: 3 flags that are invalid are enough to ge flag banned? That sounds a bit strange...

Comment: @BradLarson I will add this as a bug because I can flag normally but in Triage I get this error.